# Changing background colour of toggle after click via custom JS in wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am currently trying to add a custom JS function (via the Live Code Editor Plugin) to my wordpress website. The goal is to change the background colour of a toggle after click (i.e. from red -> green). I have tried this function but although the selector works for CSS, the JS function is not working:

CSS:

`\23 toggle-id-1 {
    background-color: red;
}`

JS:

```
var \23 toggle-id-1 = document.getElementById("\23 toggle-id-1");
```

`\23 toggle-id-1.onclick = function(){
        \23 toggle-id-1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }`

In JSFiddle this worked without any problems, is there anything different for this plugin?

Thank you!

Comment: just use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution:

```js
    $("#toggle-id-1").click(function () {
       $(this).toggleClass("green");
    });
```

```css
    #toggle-id-1 {
        background-color: red;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
            
     #toggle-id-1.green { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle-id-1" class=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have spaces in variable names. Name your variable something else.